# How to convert Game Rotation Vector sensor result to axis angles

Tags: android, rotation, game-physics, android-sensors, motion-detection

Refer to the code below, I got 4 numbers from the Game_Rotation_Vector sensor event and what I want to achieve is to get the axis angle rotation of my phone.

eg. If I rotate the phone screen counter clock wise for 90 degress, I want to get the actual value 90deg from the sensor data.

Can anyone provide the code to convert the 4 game rotation vector values to 3 axis angle values?

Comment: It looks ok apart from the rt stuff, what's that for?

Comment: That is to convert the radius to angles.  If I turn my phone 180 degree, ya only changed from -40 to 40.  That should be -90 to 90.  Not sure anything wrong with my code.

Comment: xa, xy, and xz aren't angles, they're coordinates of an axis, read the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The values are placed into the unit quaternion [like so](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-types.html#rotation_vector):

```
sensors_event_t.data[0] = rot_axis.x*sin(theta/2);
sensors_event_t.data[1] = rot_axis.y*sin(theta/2);
sensors_event_t.data[2] = rot_axis.z*sin(theta/2);
sensors_event_t.data[3] = cos(theta/2)
```

So the reverse of that is just:

```
double theta = Math.acos(vals[3])*2;
double sinv = Math.sin(theta/2);

double xa = vals[0]/sinv;
double ya = vals[1]/sinv;
double za = vals[2]/sinv;
```

**But** xa, xy, and xz aren't angles, they're coordinates of an axis as described in the documentation. I'm not sure what you want with these, you are likely better off trying to achieve your unstated goal with the unit quaternion directly.

The reason a [unit quaternion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) is used is to avoid [gimble lock](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock), basically you cannot describe every possible rotation in terms of three angles, roll/pitch/yaw, for example at a certain pitch and yaw angle you can lose the ability to roll.

So one way to make use of this is to convert into a rotation matrix:

[Source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/os/RotationVectorDemo.java)

```
if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
    // convert the rotation-vector to a 4x4 matrix. the matrix
    // is interpreted by Open GL as the inverse of the
    // rotation-vector, which is what we want.
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(
            mRotationMatrix , event.values);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, I misunderstood the rot_axis to axis angles.
So how to get the axis angle from quaternion values? I've lost in the mathematics and need some code example.

Comment: Like I said I think you be better not doing this, but I don't know the bigger picture, i.e. What are you going to do with the angles?

Comment: The angles will be used to control the mouse cursor position of my laptop.
For example, if I turn my head from left to right, the mouse cursor will follow because the distance between my phone and my laptop screen can be measured and configured.
So I really need to know the angle my phone has turned.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what turning your head has to do with these angles. Anyway, if you have a preconfigured distance, why would you care about the angles, you simply need to use the quaternion to rotate a point at that distance and intersect it with a plane that represents the monitor screen.

Comment: A simple way would be to convert into a rotation matrix. Obsessing over the value of the angles is of no use and is making it vastly more complicated than it need be.

Answer (score 0):

So we know that the rotation vector data is an unit quaternion.

Luckily, there is a page on wikipedia about quaternions conversion.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles

Two examples are provided. One in C++, one in Python. I will add them here.

C++:

```
static void toEulerAngle(const Quaterniond& q, double& roll, double& pitch, double& yaw)
{
    // roll (x-axis rotation)
    double sinr = +2.0 * (q.w() * q.x() + q.y() * q.z());
    double cosr = +1.0 - 2.0 * (q.x() * q.x() + q.y() * q.y());
    roll = atan2(sinr, cosr);

    // pitch (y-axis rotation)
    double sinp = +2.0 * (q.w() * q.y() - q.z() * q.x());
    if (fabs(sinp) >= 1)
        pitch = copysign(M_PI / 2, sinp); // use 90 degrees if out of range
    else
        pitch = asin(sinp);

    // yaw (z-axis rotation)
    double siny = +2.0 * (q.w() * q.z() + q.x() * q.y());
    double cosy = +1.0 - 2.0 * (q.y() * q.y() + q.z() * q.z());  
    yaw = atan2(siny, cosy);
}
```

Python:

```
import math

def quaternion_to_euler_angle(w, x, y, z):
    ysqr = y * y

    t0 = +2.0 * (w * x + y * z)
    t1 = +1.0 - 2.0 * (x * x + ysqr)
    X = math.degrees(math.atan2(t0, t1))

    t2 = +2.0 * (w * y - z * x)
    t2 = +1.0 if t2 > +1.0 else t2
    t2 = -1.0 if t2 < -1.0 else t2
    Y = math.degrees(math.asin(t2))

    t3 = +2.0 * (w * z + x * y)
    t4 = +1.0 - 2.0 * (ysqr + z * z)
    Z = math.degrees(math.atan2(t3, t4))

    return X, Y, Z
```

Note that in Android's unit quaternion, the Scalar component of the rotation vector is the last variable (of the four). In these code snippets, it's the first variable.

I hope this helps!